# Visiting Rio de Janeiro, Brazil as a volunteer for the 2016 Olympics what funds do I need for a visa, and in what form?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, brazil, proof-provenance-of-funds, volunteering

I am an Indian citizen (and resident) traveling to Rio de Janeiro, Brazil as a volunteer for the Olympics in Aug 2016, at the invitation of the Olympic Committee. However, all expense of travel and stay is on us. Only food and transport is free, that is, given by the Rio Olympic Committee.

I have already purchased my flight return ticket and paid all expense towards stay to Airbnb.

How much balance in my savings account should I show while applying for a visa?

What extra financial supportive document can I give?

Can I give FD certificates and share certificates?

I have all documents ready.

Comment: Can you please edit the question and add your nationality?

Comment: Yes I am from India. An Indian.

Comment: As a general rule, you should never purchase air tickets or make non-refundable hotel reservations until you have a visa unless the country you are visiting specifically requires that you do so first (and even then you often want to buy refundable airfares, cancel them, and buy a cheaper non-refundable ticket after you have the visa).

Comment: What is my question and what have you answered ? I already have bought a ticket and the stay is confirmed and I have no regrets in that. Can you throw some light on the balance needed and other supportive docs needed for the visa ?

Comment: @IndiraMullick That is why Zach provided a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Does the Rio Olympic Committee not have a package of information for their international volunteers and, possibly, a group that will help with that process? I'd contact them, as they have probably already streamlined the process for you as much as they can. (i.e. providing documentation from the organizing committee stating that you are, in fact, going to be there to volunteer, not emigrate.)

Comment: Are you sure you need a visa? If you are credentialed for the Olympics by the IOC, your Olympic ID card (which should have been sent to you prior to your departure) is your visa. You shouldn't need an additional visa. That's part of the IOC's deal with every Olympic host nation. If you're credentialed by someone else (e.g. your national Olympic committee) you may still need a visa.

Answer (score 5):

[You will need to apply and obtain a Visa for Volunteer Work (VITEM I) to visit Brazil to work as a volunteer.](http://cglondres.itamaraty.gov.br/en-us/types_of_visas.xml#voluntary) You are not allowed to do so on a tourist visa. To apply for a visa [you will need to provide the following documents](http://cglondres.itamaraty.gov.br/en-us/list_of_uploading_documents_for_visa.xml):

> ### Voluntary work (VITEM I)
>
> 1. Applicant’s valid passport – ID page;
> 2. Visa Request Form Receipt – photo and signature;
> 3. Police check certificate;
> 4. Proof of professional experience or qualification compatible with the work to be carried out. Any document submitted to prove this qualification, has to have been notarised (attested) by a notary public of the FCO, prior to submission to the Visa Section. Please bring this original(s) notarised, plus an ordinary photocopy of it. If the document is issued by another country, it has to have been legalised by the Brazilian Diplomatic Mission in that country;
> 5. Letter of invitation from the Brazilian institution (signature certified by a notary in Brazil);
> 6. Document with details on work place and type of activities to be carried out by the applicant (signature certified by a notary in Brazil);
> 7. An undertaking in writing from the Brazilian institution assuming full responsibility for the maintenance of the applicant, as well as for medical and hospital expenses of the applicant and his dependants while in Brazil and for his/her return to the country of origin (signature certified by a notary in Brazil).

Now, since this is a effectively a temporary residence visa, the regulations don't seem to specify that you need to show proof of sufficient funds for the entire length of stay. My assumption is that the authorities expect most of your expenses to be taken care of by the inviting institution. Now, I would provide a paper documenting this upon application.

In addition, I would err on the safe side of things by providing [the proof of funds usually requested for tourist visas](http://cglondres.itamaraty.gov.br/en-us/list_of_uploading_documents_for_visa.xml). These are:

> 4. Proof of financial means of support during the applicant’s stay in Brazil. Bank or credit card statements from the last 3 months at least, or latest pay slips.

Also, include the booking confirmation and invoice as both a proof of accommodation and an extra proof that you can actually pay for your stay there.